# Solve for $x$: $\frac{1}{\log(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{\log(x-2)^2} = \frac{5}{12}.$

Tags: logarithms

Solve for $x$: $$\frac{1}{\log\big((x+2)^2\big)}+\frac{1}{\log\big((x-2)^2\big)} = \frac{5}{12}.$$ My Attempt: \begin{align*} & \frac{1}{\log(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{\log(x-2)^2} = \frac{5}{12} \\ \implies &\>  \frac{1}{2\log(x+2)}+\frac{1}{2\log(x-2)} = \frac{5}{12} \\ \implies & \> \frac{1}{\log(x+2)}+\frac{1}{\log(x-2)} = \frac{5}{6} \\ \implies & \> 6\log(x^2-4) = 5 \log(x-2) \log(x+2).\end{align*} Please help me how can I proceed from here?

Comment: You need to be careful with $\log((x+2)^2)=2\log(x+2)$, it holds only when both sides are defined, but first expression is defined for $x \neq -2$, while second for $x > -2$

Comment: Why do you think there is a closed form answer?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [Lograthmic equation $ \frac {1}{\log_2(x-2)^2} + \frac{1}{\log_2(x+2) ^2} =\frac5{12}$ solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996775) (it has base $2$, maybe that is what was intended? It has a nice solution then...)

Comment: @ GEdgar. There my not be. But I asked if there any.

Comment: Here (with natural log) the answer is approximately $x=9.43973090000793458249674162201$.  As noted, it does have a nice answer for log base 2.

Comment: @GEdgar I obtain $x\approx 11.3467$.

Comment: Yes 11.3467174205889005579811123786.

Comment: If this problem uses the natural logarithm, then there are only two real solutions as found by gimusi.  If it uses the logarithm base $10$, then there are in total six real solutions $\pm a,\pm b,\pm c$ with $1<a<2<b<3<c$.  If we are using the logarithm base $2$, then there are exactly two real solutions $\pm 6$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\log(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{\log(x-2)^2}$$

is even and therefore we can assume $x> 0$ with $x\neq 1$ and $x\neq 2$ ($x=0$ is not a solution).

For $0<x<1$ and $1<x<2$ we have that

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\log(x+2)}+\frac{1}{2\log(2-x)}\\\implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{2(2-x)\log^2(2-x)}-\frac{1}{2(x+2)\log^2(x+2)}$$

from whic we can conlcude that for $0<x<1$

$$f(x)> \frac2{\log 4}$$

and for $1<x<2$

$$f(x)< \frac1{\log 16}$$

For $x>2$ we have

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\log(x+2)}+\frac{1}{2\log(x-2)}\\\implies f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2(x+2)\log^2(x+2)}-\frac{1}{2(x-2)\log^2(x-2)}<0$$

therefore on that interval $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing and since

- $\lim_{x\to 2^+} f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$

by IVT exactly a real solution exists which can be determined numerically and leads to $x\approx 11.3467$. For symmetry also $x\approx -11.3467$ is a solution.